# How to handle files in case-sensitive way in Vagrant on Windows host

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

On My Windows 8 I've installed VirtualBox + Vagrant. I used [Laravel Homestead (with Ubuntu)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#included-software) as box. When running site on this VM or running command line I would expect it is being run on Linux and not on Windows. But I found some strange issue:

First my folder mappings:

```
folders:
    - map: D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\projects\testprovag\strony
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/my-first-app/public
```

When I run in my browser `http://learn.app:8000` I got correct output - page from `/home/vagrant/code/my-first-app/public` what is the same as code from `D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\projects\testprovag\strony\my-first-app/public` just to be clear.

**Now the problem:**

In my `public` folder I've created 2 simple files:

File with name `test`  (it's empty) and file `index.php` with content:

```
<?php 

if (file_exists('TEST')) {
    echo "file exists";
}
else {
    echo "file NOT exists";
}
```

So now I run `http://learn.app:8000` in browser and I get output `file exists`. This is the result I wouldn't expect. As far as I know in Linux (my box is Ubuntu) you may have files with different case in names (in opposite to Windows) so I would expect I got `file NOT exists`.

I've tested it in my VM running `php index.php` and I get exact same result `file exists` what is again unexpected.

Now what I did I copied those 2 files to other directory on my VM `/home/vagrant/TESTS` - this directory is not mapped using Vagrant. Now when I run  `php index.php` I get `file NOT exists` what is expected result.

To be honest I completely doesn't understand it. **Question** - does PHP when using Vagrant mapping operating on VM filesystem (in this case Ubuntu) or on Virtual BOX host filesystem (in my case Windows). Is there any way to make it work to get desired result? I know this question might be a bit software related but it's really connected to PHP and Laravel and maybe I miss something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this issue can be solved not using Samba or too much work.

In Windows `cmd` I run:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

It installed a [plugin for NFS for Windows](https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd) although at http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html you have clear info that NFS doesn't work for Windows:

> Windows users: NFS folders do not work on Windows hosts. Vagrant will ignore your request for NFS synced folders on Windows.

I modified my `Homestead.yaml` file mapping from:

```
folders:
    - map: D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\projects\testprovag\strony
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

to:

```
folders:
    - map: D:\DaneAplikacji\easyphp\data\localweb\projects\testprovag\strony
      to: /home/vagrant/code
      type: "nfs"
```

(probably if not using Homestead.yaml you can add `type: nfs`, something like that: `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"` in your `Vagrantfile`)

Now when I run

`vagrant up`

I got 2 or 3 notices for admin password (probably some Windows configuration of NFS - it will appear only when I run `vagrant up` first after adding NFS type) but now both for using url `http://learn.app:8000` I got for the case from question `file NOT exists` and the same when I run `php index.php` in box commandline.

Note: this solution doesn't make you can create `test` and `TEST` files in the same directory and you will have them in your file system. It seems to handle file in case sensitive way, so if you create a file in wrong case in your app (and later in your code you want to load it/require) you will notice that it doesn't work on your Vagrant Linux box (and it would work on Windows WAMP and you would be suprised when moving on production).

Comment: I did this. Whilst it solved the file sensitive issue, I was not longer able to run `phpunit` - I kept getting `Input/Output error` when I tried to run it. Does `phpunit` work for you with this solution?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange On host (Windows) when I run `phpunit StackTest.php` (use Windows installed php) and on Linux (`vagrant ssh` and `php phpunit.phar StackTest.php`) I get standard phpunit response that test failed, so it seems to be working without a problem. Are you sure earlier it was working without a problem?

Comment: Yep. I uninstalled the package, removed 'nfs' and now it works again. I'll muck around with it some more in the next couple of days and let you know - there is probably a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the default vagrant share that you use the mounted folder still provided by the underlying file system. It won't handle linux ACLs properly either.

One solution we found for this is instead of sharing the host's folder with the client, we set up samba on the guest and shared it back to the host. It's more cumbersome and you have to do more configuration but at least you app runs in an environment as it should be

Comment: Ok, so you are telling PHP knows that the file `test` is on Windows filesystem and it doesn't care if I write `TEST`, `test` or `Test` in this case ? I hopped using Vagrant + VirtualBox will handle files exactly as they were running on Linux webserver because files exist also on Linux filesystem (synchro between Windows and Linux)

Comment: No, PHP doesn't know. But all file system functions are in fact a call to the file system. It will perform a system call to get if the file is there. It does not need to know what kind of file system it is as long it support `POSIX` (I think) but PHP will depend on the file system's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I use Windows 7 with Homestead - and I also assumed that the case sensitivity file issue would be handled by Vagrant. But I ran some similar tests - and you are correct - it is actually case insensitive.

I can confirm the issue is not to do with PHP at all - the issue actually occurs inside Vagrant on the command line itself:

```
touch EXAMPLE
rm example
```

That passes on the Vagrant box when I am SSH into it. But on a real Ubuntu box (I tested it on my server) - that command fails.

The reason is that Vagrant is calling to Windows to check if the file exists for the mapped folders. But if you make a virtual non-mapped folder inside of Vagrant - then the 'call' to see if the file exists remains inside of Vagrant and thus handled only by Ubuntu - and that is why your other test passed.

I tried turning on Case Sensitivity for Windows 7 as [documented here](https://superuser.com/q/266110/256179) - but it didnt solve the problem